# Yii2 dataprovider table checkboxColumn set checked conditionally

Tags: yii2

I have a table with checkbox for each row and I am trying to check those that have a value greater than 1000.

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $debts,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
            'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 24px;']
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
            'checked' => function($model){
                return $model->amount > 1000 ? true : false;
            }
        ],
```

But id does not work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
'checkboxOptions' => function ($model) {
    return $model->amount > 1000 ? ['checked' => true] : [];
}
```

See [checkboxOptions docs](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.14.1/framework/grid/CheckboxColumn.php#L49-L67)